# Does the spell "Scry Dungeon" give you the gold of the treasures?

Tags: lizard-wizard

In the game Lizard Wizard from Forbidden Games, the spell 'Scry Dungeon' said 'Look at the top 10 cards in the Dungeon deck, and keep all Treasure Cards'.

If you play 'Scry Dungeon' and take treasures that give you gold, do you also get the gold from those treasures?

Edit to clarify: I already think that you get the gold cards as they are treasure cards, so count at the end of the game for the "player with more treasures". But I don't know if you also get the gold coins associated with them as if they were found entering the dungeon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Gold and Items from the Dungeon Deck are both considered to be Treasure Cards. If you run across gold, you take the gold. Otherwise, you hold onto the item for endgame victory points.

From page 13 of the [Rulebook](https://www.forbiddengames.net/games/lizard-wizard/) regarding **Entering The Dungeon**:

> If it is a Treasure Card (Gold or Item)...

There are 2 types of treasure: **Gold** or **Items**.

> I already think that you get the gold card as it's a treasure card so you can count it in the end of the game for the "player with more treasures"

Gold cards **do not** count for endgame "player with the most treasures". The player with the most treasure only counts for **Items**. Gold is not considered an item and is only counted for 1 victory point per gold at the end of the game. For reference, in the scoring section on page 15 of the rulebook:

> Gold Coins score VP equal to the value of the coins

> The player with the most **Treasure Items**: 10 VP

Comment: I have added more information on the question. I think you answer is still valid, but if you are more explicit about the gold coin instead of the card, it would be great.

Comment: Nothing explicitly explains the Scry Dungeon spell card, but I believe it should clear things up between the Entering The Dungeon and Scoring sections. There are either Gold or Item Treasure Cards. No card encompasses Gold and an Item, so you either get the Gold to count as 1VP per Gold or add the Item to your collection for endgame scoring. Gold cards do not count as Treasure Items and thus do not count toward the endgame scoring of who has the most Treasure Item Cards.

Comment: Are the gold cards returned to the deck after the gold is collected?

Comment: @PhoneixS No, only monsters are ever shuffled back into the dungeon deck.